# Iterating datetime field in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array that looks like below.  I wanted to pull out the data day by day and run a function on that.  I tried doing it brute force (code snippet below) but that does not quite work either.  I'm sure there is a function of some sort that will just pull out the parts of array that correspond to particular day and pass that subset to my function:

```
while i < len(stoch_osc):
    print('value of i is: ', i, ' Valuate of i+delta is: ', i + delta)
    print(stoch_osc[i:i + delta, ])
    some_function(stoch_osc[i:i + delta, ])
    i = i + delta
```

```
stoch_osc is an array that looks like this (timestamp in datetime 
followed by a bunch of values).  I get below output by doing print(stoch_osc):
 
[[Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:32:00') 4276.0 4276.0 ... 4275.25 83 64.28]

 [Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:33:00') 4275.5 4276.25 ... 4276.25 105 78.57]

 [Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:34:00') 4276.25 4276.75 ... 4275.5 10167.85]

 [Timestamp('2021-10-04 01:31:00') 4331.0 4333.0 ... 4332.25 582 71.21]]
```

Comment: could you plz provide the result of Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:33:00') is it a timestamp like in this format `1545730073` ?

Comment: so Timestamp is basically the same as "2021-10-01 00:32:00"?

Comment: That is not a function - it's the array itself.  When I print out array, that is how it displays in console

Comment: oh okay so it is a type okay

Comment: so could you add an example of your stoch_osc list so we can work with it bc the output does not help very much

Comment: that is the input...I want to be able to say something like this:

`For date in stoch_osc
    print all values with that date
`
and have that print all values with 2021-10-01;  and then print 2021-10-04...and so on.

Comment: you are confusing me in your question you say this is the output of printing stoch_osc  and now you say that you cant give some example lines out of stoch_osc but you can print it nothing more ?

Comment: I got that.  but I am still not sure what this `Timestamp(date)` means it could have any format that I don't know. It could be "16196616161" or "2021-10.01 15:23". I don't know that's why I asked u if you could give me that information on what the  actual format of `Timestamp(date)`is

Comment: format is: '2021-10-04 01:31:00'

Comment: okay thy with that i can work :) give me a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will loop over the input and will add all the items of the input to the list data_of_day that have the same day as given.

```
day = "04"

data_of_day = [input[i] for i in range(len(input)) if input[i][0][8:10] == day]

print(data_of_day)
```

Comment: @Val S did you try it out

Comment: thanks Gerda.  got error: 'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable
if I could do range(input[0] as Date] or something like that - that would work and be more generic than hardcoding a particular day (which i may not know in advance)

Comment: I got this far   
 `unique_dates=[]   
for i in range(len(stoch_osc)):   
    unique_dates.append(stoch_osc[i][0].date())   

for i in np.unique(unique_dates):  
        print(i)`  

which gives me the list of unique dates.  now i just have to somehow reference that to the array where input[i][0] like that date, and shove it into a variable which I could then put into a function before looping to next date

Comment: I figured it out!  thank you so much for your help

`for i in np.unique(unique_dates):
       reduced_array = [[stoch_osc[j]] for j in range(len(stoch_osc)) if stoch_osc[j][0].date() == i]`